# nginx POST Port Rewriting

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy in Docker sitting in front of a web application, and it's working for the most part except for POST requests. I need to be able to accept connections from any URL and port and proxy it to a specific hostname and port for the web application. This works for normal web requests but falls apart for POST. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen *:8080;
    server_name _;

    proxy_set_header Host 127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/
        rewrite "^(/.+?):\d+?/(.+?)$" $1:8080/$2 break;
    }
}
```

The server will only accept connections from `127.0.0.1:8080` when authenticating a user. I'm using nginx:1.13.6-alpine. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is sample log output from the web server:

```
17:11:26,435 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-1) javax.servlet.ServletException: CORS origin denied 127.0.0.1:7001 not on allowed list:[]
```

Here is the log entry from the nginx container:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2017:17:11:26 +0000] "POST /suite/auth?environment=tempo HTTP/1.1" 401 996 "http://127.0.0.1:7001/suite/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I'm trying to launch multiple instances of the web application in a Docker Swarm cluster, but I don't have the ability to dynamically assign IP addresses or hostnames, so I was going to use unique port numbers for each instance. I'm trying to get nginx to proxy the requests for me so that I can launch as many unique instances as I need to.

Comment: What is the error? Do you have the logs?

Comment: You cannot rewrite a POST request because rewriting will change it to a GET request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out, and hopefully what I found will help others out. I ended up approaching the problem a different way; instead of attempting to rewrite the port in the HTTP headers I used the `sub_filter` plugin in nginx to rewrite the HTML being served by the application when it goes through the proxy. This way all of the links in the HTML were using the correct domain and port. Here is the config that ended up working for me:

```
server {
    listen 7001 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://app:8080/;

        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ http://$host/;

        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header Origin 127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter_types *;  
        sub_filter "127.0.0.1:8080" "$host";
    }   
}
```

For reference, a simplified version of my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  app:
    image: my-application:latest
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:latest

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.6-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:7001"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-config.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
```